# How to get the ssl_version of a Ruby SSLContext object

Tags: ruby, ssl, openssl, sslcontext

I am working on OpenSSL's SSLContext right now and created a Ruby OpenSSL object like this:

```
0> ssl_object = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new("TLSv1_2_client")
=> #<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext:0x7acec6db>
```

which created an instance of the `SSLContext` object. I can change this SSLContext object by using:

```
ssl_object.ssl_version="SSLv2_3"
```

However, I want to understand/get that `ssl_version` of `ssl_object`. How do I do that?

When I do:

```
0> ssl_object.ssl_version
=> undefined method `ssl_version' for #<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext:0x38106bc4>
Did you mean?  ssl_version=
```

According to the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/SSL/SSLContext.html), there's only a setter, not a getter.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can create a fake socket:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(
  UNIXSocket.pair.first, 
  OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new("SSLv3")
).ssl_version
=> "SSLv3"
```

Comment: This seems to return `"SSLv23"` regardless of what you set it

Comment: You sure this doesn't just return the default ssl_version?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage if so, there is no other way as the C wrapper doesn't define a getter: https://github.com/ruby/openssl/blob/3dd75865b7bf7bd5b89eb760c2e131a27bdd1d43/ext/openssl/ossl_ssl.c#L2542

Comment: Yeah that's what I saw and what I believed was true as well. Thanks for trying!

Comment: @theGreenCabbage see my update, looks like `SSLSocket` defines the `ssl_version` getter.

Comment: Hm. As far as I can tell, I don't use `SSLSocket` (I could be wrong).

Comment: Please explain why the code is appropriate. [Teach, don't merely answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291533/128421) Also, don't use "update" or "edit" tags in your text. Incorporate the change as if it'd been there initially. See "[Should 'Edit:' in edits be discouraged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255685/128421)"

Comment: @theGreenCabbage Create a fake one to get the version :)

Comment: I'm not "being a pain". I'm trying to educate a user how the site is supposed to look. The linked information is the consensus of our peers on the site's "look and feel" and it takes everyone's effort to get there.

Comment: now version is deprecated, you must use min_version and max_version